# boost::gregorian::date.day_number() returns Julian date

Tags: datetime, boost

I have noticed that `boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1).day_number()` returns `2440588`, which is its Julian date.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is exactly the problem?

Comment: I want to compute the difference between two dates in days and I wondered what "epoch start" is in the boost documentation (very bottom of www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between dates in days:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/adaf0af0f795a8b5)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_date.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using boost::gregorian::date;
    date a(1712, 1, 1);
    date b(1713, 1, 1);

    std::cout << (b - a).days() << "\n"; // 366, includes 30th February 1712
}
```

The epoch is 1400-01-01:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99f23d11c19fef9d)</kbd>**

```
auto epoch = boost::gregorian::gregorian_calendar::epoch();
std::cout << date(epoch.year, epoch.month, epoch.day) << "\n";
```

The [introduction section in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html) says:

> The implemented calendar is a "proleptic Gregorian calendar" which extends dates back prior to the Gregorian Calendar's first adoption in 1582. The current implementation supports dates in the range 1400-Jan-01 to 9999-Dec-31. Many references will represent dates prior to 1582 using the Julian Calendar, so caution is in order if accurate calculations are required on historic dates. See Calendrical Calculations by Reingold & Dershowitz for more details. Date information from Calendrical Calculations has been used to cross-test the correctness of the Gregorian calendar implementation.

Comment: I read that, too. But `boost::gregorian::date(1400,1,1).day_number()` is `2232400`, so the true day zero is still over 6000 years before that. And you cannot create dates prior to 1400-Jan-01.

Comment: So this doesn't answer my question, since `day_number()` doesn't actually count the number of days since `epoch()`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Seems that your definition of epoch might be based on the wrong assumptions (epoch is not a hard defined term). Other than that, the documentation might be confusingly worded.

Comment: I don't think explanations will get more authoritative than the snippet I quoted. You could get someone to clarify on the boost mailing list?